# Noone else can access my website

Tags: wordpress, connections

i recently changed my website to use Word Press and it was working fine before, i was getting traffic and stuff like that, but since i recently switched, it seems my site is not accessible by others. I can access it locally (Hosted at home) but i tried getting a rating on nibbler, and that failed, then tried downforeveryone and that failed aswell.

I don't understand what has happened, i simply switched to Word Press while i design a new website, and it just won't work anymore. I am running my server off a Raspberry Pi if that helps.

Website: http://miworldmc.tk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is probably a case where what you did has nothing to do with what went wrong.*

**It seems your domain name is not in the DNS servers anymore.** Chrome says something to that effect and nslookup returns that it cannot find your domain.

Check with your registrar to see if your domain has expired or has been transferred without your knowledge. There has been cases where fraudsters hijack a domain.

If you domain is still registered to you, check the DNS servers themselves and make sure your records point to the right location.

Comment: Resolves for me, just times out :P

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie Aha! It resolves now but to a private IP address. You must give it a public address, the one assigned by the ISP TO your modem (Cable/ADSL/DSL). If you have a router or gateway in-between you have to also make a proper port forward for HTTP connection to resolve to your server. As Stephen said, it your address is not static, it may also change without notice.

Comment: It is a static address. Would someone mind testing it now?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: it does? Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I concur with another answer that says that this is a DNS problem.

Keep in mind that if you are hosting this at home, most ISPs will change your IP address from time to time.  You will need to use a dynamic dns service to keep your dns record pointing to an ever changing IP address.

Comment: I am currently using a static IP address.